# Does Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF) supports Jersey or RestEasy services?

Tags: rest, jersey, cloud, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am developing a new application and I want that to be deployed on PCF(Cloud Foundry). I am thinking which flavor of REST services that I have to use. Should I use Jersey or RestEasy to expose services? or cloud foundry provides default rest implementations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Foundry does not provide any rest implementation, and can support almost any, if it's supported by a language with a buildpack. Jersey and RestEasy would both be supported as they can run in a JVM, as is Spring Boot (which is my personal favorite). You can also write REST services in ruby, python, go, php, and nodejs--and those are just the languages that are supported out of the box!